# Moving an ID to the next element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to move an ID that is in an element to the next select element on the page. I have to do this because of software that is used to write the select boxes does not allow classes or ids to be directly applied to select elements. I also want it to be automated so that if I have 20 select boxes I don't have 20 separate lines of jQuery.

Here is the current code:

```
<div id="stack" class="moveID">
    <select name="overflow">
        <option value="hi">Hi</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is what I would like to happen.

```
<div class="moveID">
    <select name="overflow" id="stack">
        <option value="hi">Hi</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're describing is not the "next" element (which suggests the next sibling) but the immediate child element. You probably mean the immediate child or the next sibling on the same level. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you requested, to automate this for all items with the class `moveID`, you could use this:

```
$('.moveID').each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $(this).removeAttr('id').children().first().attr('id', id);
});
```

Comment: +1 Using `removeAttr` and continuing the chaining is the most elegant way.

Comment: @AtesGoral but not as efficient as just using DOM methods - sometimes jQuery makes people forget how easy that can be...

Comment: And we need an innerHTML + RegExp solution to demonstrate the far end.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('.moveID'), function(){
  var moveTo = $(this + ':first-child');
  $(moveTo).attr('id', $(this).attr('id'));
  $(this).removeAttr('id');
})
```

Comment: This assumes all input elements will have the name "overflow"

Comment: Last edit, then I'm out. This is getting too flooded. Everyone is racing to get the answer in without thinking first. Myself included

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each select element has a .moveID (direct) wrap:

```
$("select").each(function () {

    // or this.id = $(this).closest(".moveID")[0].id;
    this.id = $(this).parent()[0].id;
    $(this).parent().removeAttr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id= $(".moveID").attr("id");
$(".moveID").removeAttr("id").find("select").attr("id",id);
```

Of course, this would add the same ID to as many select's there is, which is bad. So you might want to use classes instead:

```
var id= $(".moveID").attr("id");
$(".moveID").removeAttr("id").find("select").addClass(id);
```

(updated)

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
$('.moveID').each(function() {
    // record current ID
    var id = this.id;

    // find the first HTMLElement inside
    var child = this.firstChild;
    while (child && child.nodeType != 1) {
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }

    // if found, swap the IDs
    if (child) {
        this.removeAttribute('id');
        child.setAttribute('id', id);
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/dqN8n/3/

This uses jQuery to find the elements to move, but then uses native DOM methods to actually make the changes.  This will be much more efficent that the alternative:

```
$('.moveID').each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $(this).removeAttr('id').children().first().attr('id', id);
}
```

because there's no creation of lots of intermediate jQuery objects, and there's (at most) two function calls instead of five.

Comment: That doesn't meet "I also want it to be automated so that if I have 20 select boxes I don't have 20 separate lines of jQuery."

Comment: @KyleMacey oops, missed that bit...  fixed now

Comment: The non-jQuery version has to be really careful that `firstChild` is actually the desired element.  A few spaces in the HTML can cause firstChild to be a text node.  That is one of the advantages of using jQuery as it skips right over text nodes and finds you actual elements only.

Comment: I tried your non-jQuery version.  It doesn't work because there's no method called `removeAttr`.  And, when you fix that, it doesn't work because it selects a text node, not the select node.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're looking at an old version.

Comment: Gives a syntax error until you add a closing ')'.  Then, the code doesn't work.  It doesn't end up finding the proper child node.  You need to test your own code here.  I'm done testing it for you.  That's four separate errors I found in it.  Perhaps others can see some of the benefits of using jQuery.  A lot less code and a lot simpler to write.  I'm sure this could work, but you don't have it yet and aren't testing your own code.  jsFiddle where it doesn't work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VPcYA/

Comment: @jfriend00 it's already tested and working now.  The brace and removeAttr were silly typos (too late here) - the thing about finding text nodes was the only genuine error.